# How to change the text through code in matplotlib TextBox widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget

I have a matplotlib widget Textbox as follows

```
temp_descr = 'wow'
self.axLabel = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.21, 0.075])
self.text_boxLabel = TextBox(self.axLabel, 'Label: ', temp_descr)
```

Once it is set to its initial value, how can I later change the text? Like

```
temp_descr = 'new wow'
self.text_boxLabel.set_text(temp_descr)
```

However, this gives the following error

> AttributeError: 'TextBox' object has no attribute 'set_text'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not only want to set the text which is shown but also change the text which is internally stored. To do this all at once use the `TextBox`'s `.set_val()` method.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.widgets

temp_descr = 'wow'
axLabel = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.21, 0.075])
textbox = matplotlib.widgets.TextBox(axLabel, 'Label: ', temp_descr)

textbox.set_val("jojojo")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering how to do it the "wrong" way, [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/146de7ff5247e9d75a4dcbf93dec556a0efc639e/lib/matplotlib/widgets.py#L720) it is:

```
textbox.text = "foo, bar and baz"
```

This will update the display without updating the internal state, which could be useful to mock the "initial" functionality. Just beware that it will introduce some hard to find inconsistencies.